# Tensorflow TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'> while finding gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, backpropagation, tensorflow-gradient

It's a text analysis task with CNN model,I want to visualize which word is triggering most to my particular classification,Here is my code

```
with tf.Session() as sess:    

saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/home/rakesh/WORK/CNN_Lookout/runs/1519022246/checkpoints/model-200.meta') #load graph
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/home/rakesh/WORK/CNN_Lookout/runs/1519022246/checkpoints/./')) #load weigt

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
input_x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input_x:0")
input_y = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input_y:0")
dropout_keep_prob=graph.get_tensor_by_name("dropout_keep_prob:0")    
embedding_W= graph.get_tensor_by_name("embedding/W:0")

embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_W, input_x)
embedded_chars_expanded = tf.expand_dims(embedded_chars, -1) 

conv_maxpool_5_W= graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv-maxpool-5/W:0")
conv_maxpool_5_b= graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv-maxpool-5/b:0")
conv_maxpool_5_conv= graph.get_operation_by_name("conv-maxpool-5/conv")
conv_maxpool_5_relu= graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv-maxpool-5/relu:0")
conv_maxpool_5_pool= graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv-maxpool-5/pool:0")

conv_maxpool_7_W= graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv-maxpool-7/W:0")
conv_maxpool_7_b= graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv-maxpool-7/b:0")
conv_maxpool_7_conv= graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv-maxpool-7/conv:0")
conv_maxpool_7_relu= graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv-maxpool-7/relu:0")
conv_maxpool_7_pool= graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv-maxpool-7/pool:0")

conv_maxpool_9_W= graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv-maxpool-9/W:0")
conv_maxpool_9_b= graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv-maxpool-9/b:0")
conv_maxpool_9_conv= graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv-maxpool-9/conv:0")
conv_maxpool_9_relu= graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv-maxpool-9/relu:0")
conv_maxpool_9_pool= graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv-maxpool-9/pool:0")

# Combine all the pooled features
num_filters_total = 128 * 3
pooled_outputs = [conv_maxpool_5_pool,conv_maxpool_7_pool,conv_maxpool_9_pool]
print(conv_maxpool_5_pool.shape)
h_pool = tf.concat(pooled_outputs,3)
h_pool_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool, [-1, num_filters_total])   

final_w= graph.get_tensor_by_name("W:0")
final_b= graph.get_tensor_by_name("output/b:0")



# Unpooling       
Ps = (tf.gradients(conv_maxpool_5_pool, conv_maxpool_5_relu))[0]
unpooled = tf.multiply(Ps, conv_maxpool_5_relu)
print(sess.run(unpooled,feed_dict))
print(sess.run(unpooled,feed_dict).shape)
#print(sess.run(conv_maxpool_5_relu,feed_dict))

# Deconv
batch_size = tf.shape(input_x)[0]
ds = [batch_size]
ds.append(embedded_chars_expanded.get_shape()[1])
ds.append(embedded_chars_expanded.get_shape()[2])
ds.append(embedded_chars_expanded.get_shape()[3])
deconv_shape = tf.stack(ds)
deconv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(
    unpooled,
    conv_maxpool_5_W,
    deconv_shape,
    strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
    padding='VALID',
    name="Deconv"
    )
print(sess.run(deconv,feed_dict))
print(sess.run(deconv,feed_dict).shape)
print(sess.run(embedded_chars_expanded,feed_dict).shape)
#reshaped to original w2v embeding
embedded_chars_expanded_shape=sess.run(embedded_chars_expanded,feed_dict).shape
embedded_chars_back=tf.reshape(deconv,[embedded_chars_expanded_shape[0],embedded_chars_expanded_shape[1],embedded_chars_expanded_shape[2]])
print(sess.run(embedded_chars_back,feed_dict))
print(sess.run(embedded_chars_back,feed_dict).shape)
print(sess.run(embedded_chars,feed_dict))
print(sess.run(embedded_chars,feed_dict).shape)
#original input
print(sess.run(input_x, feed_dict))
print(sess.run(input_x, feed_dict).shape)
input_back = (tf.gradients(embedded_chars_back, input_x))[0]
#print(sess.run(input_back , feed_dict))
#input_back = tf.multiply(input_back, input_x)
#print(sess.run(input_back ,feed_dict).shape)
```

The last part where I want to get the original input by using gradient from embednding layer , the result is becoming None type, I am using Google word2vec model to get embedding in forward pass.

```
input_back = (tf.gradients(embedded_chars_back, input_x))[0]  #becoming none

print(sess.run(input_back , feed_dict))
```

#### I---->error of last line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 155, in <module>
File "/home/rakesh/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/home/rakesh/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1105, in _run
self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
File "/home/rakesh/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 414, in __init__
self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
File "/home/rakesh/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 231, in for_fetch
(fetch, type(fetch)))
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

I want to visualize the last cnn layer till the input so I wanted to find out how much is backpropagated till input, which word contribute most,

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an explicit question, but I am assuming you are wondering why gradients return a `None`. `tf.gradients` (and various similar methods) return `None` when there is no sequences of differentiable operations connecting the `x` to the `y` (or if you explicitly called `stop_gradients`).

If it is not clear from the code (it is not to me), where the disconnect is, you can view the graph in tensorboard or you can try to bisect the sequence of operations between `x` and `y` to narrow down on the exact place where the gradient becomes `None`.